# POST and PUT request block on geoserver, NGINX after installing https certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, tomcat, geoserver

I recently installed the SSL certification on my web-application on [NGINX using cartbot](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-centos-8). I have added the reverse proxy for GeoServer in `nginx.conf` file as below,

```
 location /geoserver {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_redirect off;
         }
```

I also enable the CORS by editing the `web.xml` file as below,

```xml
  <context-param>
    <param-name>GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST</param-name>
    <param-value>pgeo.ait.ac.th</param-value>
  </context-param>


    <filter>
      <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
      <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS</param-value>
      </init-param>
      <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
      </init-param>
    </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Before installing the SSL certificate, everything was fine. But after installation of the SSL certificate, I can only do the GET and DELETE request using GeoServer REST curl and unable to do the PUT and POST request.
I confused, whether it is the error from GeoServer or Nginx. Please help me to find the solution.

**PS:** Although the GeoServer admin interface is working fine. I can do everything from there.

I found the following questions but didn't help to find the exact solution,

1. [GeoServer behind Nginx: web admin crashes](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/306824/geoserver-behind-nginx-web-admin-crashes)
2. [Use Nginx with Tomcat to put GeoServer under HTTPS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370337/use-nginx-with-tomcat-to-put-geoserver-under-https)

Answer (score 0):

May Be you Should try this type  of configuration on NGINX

```
error_page 403 /e403.html;


location = / {
  root   index.jsp;
  allow all;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. My geoserver being hooked to a subdomain, I managed to solved this cors issues by listing my domain and subdomain (comma separated) in the  tag of GEOSERVER_CSRF_WHITELIST

Comment: He suggested the step he took for same issues. looks ok